Почему выдаёт ошибку на bot.register_message_handler?
#Выше в коде просят прислать любое фото
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])

def answer2(message):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично.')
    else:
        quest2(message)
        
def quest2(message):
    typeError = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный формат.')
    bot.register_message_handler(typeError, answer2)

Подчёркивает жёлтым typeError и answer2. В другой ситуации такого же типа код работал корректно.

В quest2 вы ожидаете сообщение от пользователя, пока он его не отправит?

Да, жду сообщение от пользователя.

Тогда вам другой метод нужен, bot.register_next_step_handler()

Боже, не заметил вообще, час голову ломаю. Спасибо огромное!
